# Spring Security Expressions in Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

Using Spring Boot 1.5.2 and Thymeleaf 2.1, I'm trying to add some code on an HTML page to identify the role of a user.

However, all of these statements evaluate to true which is incorrect:

```
<div sec:authorize="hasAuthority('ADMIN')" > Has Authority ADMIN </div> 
<div sec:authorize="hasAuthority('USER')" > Has Authority USER </div> 
<div sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">Has Role ROLE_ADMIN</div>
<div sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_USER')">Has Role ROLE_USER</div>
<div sec:authorize="hasRole('ADMIN')">Has Role ADMIN</div>
<div sec:authorize="hasRole('USER')">Has Role USER</div>
```

**User.java**

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
private Set<Role> roles;
```

**Role.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
public class Role {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "role")
    private String role;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I fixed the issue.   I was missing three items:

**thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4**

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
  <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**xmlns:sec in the html template**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
  xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4">
```

**Correct output**

"Has authority USER" is now displayed when the template is rendered when a user with ROLE=USER is logged in

```
<div sec:authorize="hasAuthority('USER')" > Has Authority USER </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check definition `xmlns:sec` in part of your template - `html`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have sec defined in your html section of the page. Like this:

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need import in porm

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
      </dependency>

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

This is a website gui for you https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springsecurity.html

Answer (score -2):

Sounds very odd..

Are you sure that you have included Thymeleaf in your project?

If Thymeleaf is not incuded in your project/files, then the html page will render as a regular html page. So it might look like you got all roles, but in reality, the site has just rendered as regular html.

You can check if your Thymeleaf is rendering properly with this:

```
<p th:text="Hello World!" />
```